# ¿Cómo implementar un método abstracto para utilizarlo en diferentes clases, en Java?

Tags: java, método, patrones-de-diseño, clase-abstracta

Quiero saber como puedo *implementar* un **método abstracto** para utilizarlo en diferentes clases, una con un argumento y otra con dos argumentos.

Por ejemplo tengo una clase Factory **`Shape`** que alberga los métodos de sus subsclases al implementarla

```
public abstract class Shape{
    public abstract Double area(Double d);
}
```

Tengo una clase **`Square`** que la implementa

```
public class Square extends Shape{
    @Override
    public Double area (Double area){
        return Math.pow(radio, 2) * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Todo bien hasta aquí, pero tengo otra clase, **Rectangle** que en este caso utiliza dos parámetros como argumentos y en la cual al ser un **Shape** implemento la clase abstracta `Shape`.

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape{
    @Override
    public Double area(Double width, Double height){
        return width*height;
    }
}
```

Como podrán saber, el segundo objeto **`Rectangle`** dará error por el segundo parámetro que no está soportado en el método raíz.

Para solucionarlo podría hacer implementar un segundo método doblemente sobrecargado para la clase `Rectangle`, de esta forma:

```
public abstract class Shape{
    public abstract Double area(Double d);
    public abstract Double area(Double d, d2);
}
```

Sin embargo, esto haría que en cada uno de los objetos haya un método que no utilice y por tanto redunde.

Si me pueden explicar por favor qué puedo hacer en este caso para reutilizar un mismo método o para hacer que en un método no haya que implementar obligatoriamente, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo lo enfocaría diferente. Tú lo que buscas es obtener el area, y que la llamada al método sea igual en todos los casos, independientemente del tipo de objeto.
Primero defines el objeto padre:

```
public abstract class Shape{
    public abstract Double area();
}
```

Así, sin parámetros, ya que buscas que la gestión de estos recaiga en los objetos hijos.
Después, los objetos hijo:

```
public class Square extends Shape{
    private final Double radio;

    public Square(Double radio){
        this.radio = radio;
    }

    @Override
    public Double area (){
        return Math.pow(radio, 2) * Math.PI;
    }
}
public class Rectangle extends Shape{
    private final Double width;
    private final Double height;

    public Rectangle (Double width, Double height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public Double area(){
        return width*height;
    }
}
```

De esta manera, una vez instanciados los objetos, serán usados de la misma manera, independientemente de su clase.